# Where did the GetDistanceTo go in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am trying to get the distance between two GeoCoordinates on my Windows Phone 8 device and in my geolocater_PositionChanged callback I have the following line of code:

```
Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geocoordinate coord = args.Position.Coordinate;
```

From online tutorials, it looks like GetDistanceTo use to be a method of the Geocoordinate class. But neither of the coordinate classes on either side of the = sign above have that method. I know how to calculate the distance using the haversine formula but I would really like to use the built-in method.

Where is that method in the windows phone 8/8.1 api?

The answer below is correct but just so others are clear, you take the latitude and longitude from the Geocoordinate object and use those to new up an instance of the GeoCoordinate class:

```
GeoCoordinate location1 = new GeoCoordinate(longitude, latitude);
Double distance = location1.GetDistanceTo(location2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different classes: `GeoCoordinate` and `Geocoordinate`. GeoCoordinate contains `GetDistanceTo` so you have to create GeoCoordinate instance from Geocoordinate and then you can use this method.

btw: you can use `ToGeoCoordinate` (extension method) from the [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code :

```
var CurrentLocation = new GeoCoordinate(-51.39792, -0.12084);

var DestLocation = new GeoCoordinate(-29.83245, 31.04034);

double Distance = CurrentLocation.GetDistanceTo(DestLocation);
```

The distance will be in meters